# Is is better to use multiple states or environments in Lua?

Tags: c, lua, lua-api

I've got a scripted program, and I'm currently using multiple states for different environments, to ensure user and system scripts don't mess with each other.

What are the pros/cons of using multiple environments against a single context instead?

Comment: Could whoever down-voted please add a comment - this seems like a valid question about the Lua C API to me.

Comment: The advantage is, you can run all the states at the same time, and they truly are separate as long as you don't deliberately change it. The disadvantages are the need for marshalling information through the native layer, and duplication of common data.